# How do I manually blur an image in python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, coordinates, sage

In the code below I am trying to blur an image in python by replacing each pixel with the average of its surrounding pixels as long as the original pixel is not at the border of the image. However, whenever I run my code I am simply receiving a black image. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imread, imsave, imresize

imgOld = imread('house.png') # read image into a numpy array
imgNew = imgOld
(imgH, imgW, imgC) = imgOld.shape # imgC = 2 or 4 (RGB or RGBA)
plt.imshow(imgOld, origin='lower')

# blur
for y in range(imgH):
    for x in range(imgW):
        xLast = 0
        yLast = 0
        if x != 0 and y != 0:
            xLast = (x-1) % imgW
            yLast = (y-1) % imgH
        else:
            xLast = 0
            yLast = 0
        xNext = (x+1) % imgW
        yNext = (y+1) % imgH
        rgb = imgNew[y,x]
        r = (imgOld[yLast,xLast,2]
                    + imgOld[yLast,x,2]
                    + imgOld[yLast,xNext,2]
                    + imgOld[y,xLast,2]
                    + imgOld[y,x,2]
                    + imgOld[y,xNext,2]
                    + imgOld[yNext,xLast,2]
                    + imgOld[yNext,x,2]
                    + imgOld[yNext,xNext,2]) / 9
        g = (imgOld[yLast,xLast,1]
                    + imgOld[yLast,x,1]
                    + imgOld[yLast,xNext,1]
                    + imgOld[y,xLast,1]
                    + imgOld[y,x,1]
                    + imgOld[y,xNext,1]
                    + imgOld[yNext,xLast,1]
                    + imgOld[yNext,x,1]
                    + imgOld[yNext,xNext,1]) / 9
        b = (imgOld[yLast,xLast,0]
                    + imgOld[yLast,x,0]
                    + imgOld[yLast,xNext,0]
                    + imgOld[y,xLast,0]
                    + imgOld[y,x,0]
                    + imgOld[y,xNext,0]
                    + imgOld[yNext,xLast,0]
                    + imgOld[yNext,x,0]
                    + imgOld[yNext,xNext,0]) / 9
        imgNew[y,x] = [b,g,r]
plt.imshow(imgNew, origin='lower')
```

Edit: I have updated my code to average based on the individual color value of each pixel however I am still receiving a black image as a result.

I am adding my perfectly working java version of this code. I do not understand where I am going wrong

Java version:

```
protected void proc_17() {
    info = "Blur";
    for (int y = 0; y < imgH; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < imgW; x++) {
            int xLast = 0;
            int yLast = 0;
            if (x != 0 && y != 0) {
                xLast = (x-1) % imgW;
                yLast = (y-1) % imgH;
            } else {
                xLast = 0;
                yLast = 0;
            }
            int xNext = (x+1) % imgW;
            int yNext = (y+1) % imgH;
            float r = (imgOld.getR(xLast, yLast) 
                    + imgOld.getR(x, yLast) 
                    + imgOld.getR(xNext, yLast) 
                    + imgOld.getR(xLast, y) 
                    + imgOld.getR(x, y) 
                    + imgOld.getR(xNext, y) 
                    + imgOld.getR(xLast, yNext) 
                    + imgOld.getR(x, yNext) 
                    + imgOld.getR(xNext, yNext)) / 9;
            float g = (imgOld.getG(xLast, yLast) 
                    + imgOld.getG(x, yLast) 
                    + imgOld.getG(xNext, yLast) 
                    + imgOld.getG(xLast, y) 
                    + imgOld.getG(x, y) 
                    + imgOld.getG(xNext, y) 
                    + imgOld.getG(xLast, yNext) 
                    + imgOld.getG(x, yNext)
                    + imgOld.getG(xNext, yNext)) / 9;
            float b = (imgOld.getB(xLast, yLast) 
                    + imgOld.getB(x, yLast) 
                    + imgOld.getB(xNext, yLast) 
                    + imgOld.getB(xLast, y) 
                    + imgOld.getB(x, y) 
                    + imgOld.getB(xNext, y) 
                    + imgOld.getB(xLast, yNext) 
                    + imgOld.getB(x, yNext) 
                    + imgOld.getB(xNext, yNext)) / 9;
            imgNew.setR(x, y, r);
            imgNew.setG(x, y, g);
            imgNew.setB(x, y, b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at [opencv](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html)

Comment: Is this homework? Actual project? Do you know what convolution and kernels are?

Comment: you are looping over all elements. Numpy can easily do this vectorized. The information you need is not so different from the information needed for conway's game of life,, but instead of the count you need the mean of surrounding places. You could adapt something like [this](http://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/teaching/numpy/numpy.html) to your situation

Comment: @spectras It is kind of homework. I already completed this task successfully in Java but I am having trouble converting it to python. And I do not know what convolution and kernels are.

Comment: Convolution is, basically, the generic version of the operation you are trying to implement. It generates a signal from weighted displacements of a source signal. Your blur is a convolution using a 3x3 kernel filled with factor 1/9. The point being, numpy provides fully accelerated methods to perform convolution. If it was not homework it would be a much better solution to achieve what you want. But if it's homework you have to do it yourself I assume, thus the question.

Comment: Where is this related to Sage?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is that it is not adding up the values ​ in the variables r, g, and b.
This may be for reasons of indentation, so I put these values ​​as a list, made the sum, and divided it by 9.
Follow the script below:

```
 imgOld = imread('house.png') # read image into a numpy array imgNew =
 imgOld (imgH, imgW, imgC) = imgOld.shape # imgC = 2 or 4 (RGB or RGBA)
 
 plt.imshow(imgOld, vmin=0, vmax=255) plt.show()
 
 # blur for y in range(imgH):
     for x in range(imgW):
         xLast = 0
         yLast = 0
         if x != 0 and y != 0:
             xLast = (x-1) % imgW
             yLast = (y-1) % imgH
         else:
             xLast = 0
             yLast = 0
         xNext = (x+1) % imgW
         yNext = (y+1) % imgH
         rgb = imgNew[y,x]
 
         aux_r = (imgOld[yLast,xLast,2],
                       imgOld[yLast,x,2],
                       imgOld[yLast,xNext,2],
                       imgOld[y,xLast,2],
                       imgOld[y,x,2],
                       imgOld[y,xNext,2],
                       imgOld[yNext,xLast,2],
                       imgOld[yNext,x,2],
                       imgOld[yNext,xNext,2])
         r = sum(aux_r)
         r = r/9
         aux_g = (imgOld[yLast,xLast,1],
                       imgOld[yLast,x,1],
                       imgOld[yLast,xNext,1],
                       imgOld[y,xLast,1],
                       imgOld[y,x,1],
                       imgOld[y,xNext,1],
                       imgOld[yNext,xLast,1],
                       imgOld[yNext,x,1],
                       imgOld[yNext,xNext,1])
         g = sum(aux_g)
         g = g/9
 
         aux_b = (imgOld[yLast,xLast,0],
                       imgOld[yLast,x,0],
                       imgOld[yLast,xNext,0],
                       imgOld[y,xLast,0],
                       imgOld[y,x,0],
                       imgOld[y,xNext,0],
                       imgOld[yNext,xLast,0],
                       imgOld[yNext,x,0],
                       imgOld[yNext,xNext,0])
         b = sum(aux_b)
         b = b/9
             
         imgNew[y,x] = [b,g,r] plt.imshow(imgNew, vmin=0, vmx=255) plt.show()
```